# Как внести элемент списка в базу данных

Tags: python, sqlite

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(f'user_db/{str(chats_id)}.db')
pursor = conn.cursor()
conn.execute( """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(nimber)""".format(f'srid'))
conn.commit()
m = 0
try:
    get = nimber[m]
    print(get)
    for i in nimber:
        exists = pursor.execute(f"SELECT nimber FROM srid WHERE nimber = '{i}'").fetchone()
        print(exists)
        if not exists:
            print('нашел')
            pursor.execute('''INSERT INTO srid (nimber) VALUES (?)''', get)
            print('внес')
            bot.send_message(chat_id, f'{ord[m]}\n'
                                      f'{nimber[m]}\n'
                                      f'{orsu[m]}')
            m +=1
        else:
            m +=1
     else:
         pass
except KeyError:
    pass



pursor.execute('''INSERT INTO srid (nimber) VALUES (?)''', i[m]) этот код неверный, не вносит данные в таблицу
```

ошибка `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 32 supplied.`

я понял что он говорит что в данном элементе 32 символа и ты хочешь внести их только в один столбик, а нужно на каждую букву по столбику, но мне нужно чтобы он этот элемент полностью внес в один столбик nimber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pursor.execute('''INSERT INTO srid(nimber) VALUES (?)''', (get,))
```